# Fedora KDE 29 random directories in home directory

Tags: linux, fedora, kde-plasma-5

I have fresh Fedora 29 KDE spin installed. Firefox added, up to date.
After each reboot and login an empty folder with random name appears in home directory. Each time name is new and does not look like anything meaningful, more like some garbage. To give you an example, here are a few names exactly as reported by "ls -l -a"

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 12:23 ' '$'\326'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 12:21 ''$'\240\335'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 12:19 ''$'\240\355\346''3tU'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 12:18 ''$'\260\323'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 12:12 ''p'$'\351'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 12:08 '0'$'\304'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 12:05 '0'$'\305'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 11:57 '0'$'\327'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 11:53 '@'$'\327'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 11:50 'p'$'\351'
drwxrwxr-x   2 adontz adontz     6 Jan 14 11:47 'p'$'\351'
```

These directories cannot be deleted from Dolphin, only from command line.

HDD is not damaged, checked. Also, at the moment I write this, it already happens on three distinct computers. Just logout and login is not enough, restart is required, but directories are created at login moment.

Also, I have tried to use auditd/auditctl to find out which process created these folders with the following rule

```
-a exit,always -F dir=/home/"
```

then tried to find anything useful from audit log with

```
grep -P -o 'name="[^"]+"' /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

but I have found no related records.

What else can be done?

Comment: Reproduces on GNOME, so at least now I know it is not related to desktop environment which I initially suspected. Still no clue what is it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found on a different post that this seems to be the solution for now until the abrt app gets pushed through updates:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/131926/files-and-folders-with-name-invalid-encoding-what-does-it-mean-and-how-to-fix-it/

> This is a bug that should be fixed in the next version of abrt packages.
>   Upgrading abrt packages to version 2.11.1-2.fc29 is the root cause.
>
> Bug : GLib-CRITICAL: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
>   Background information and the temporary - proven to work - solution :
>
> There's a file being located in /etc/xdg/autostart, that seems to be responsible for the problem.
>   This is the symbolic link file : /etc/xdg/autostart/org.freedesktop.problems.applet.desktop
>   The file is a symlink to /usr/share/applications/org.freedesktop.problems.applet.desktop.
>
> Delete the weird folder either by using the command line, or in the nautilus application.
>   Then execute

`sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/org.freedesktop.problems.applet.desktop`

> Next time after restart of the system, you won't see newly created weird folders anymore.
>
> Bugfix Update 2019-01-14 : abrt-2.11.1-3.fc29 has been pushed to fedora updates system.
>   Current status : pending -> https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2019-b5c308118f